# Insert characters between a string in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I have data like this:

| RowA |
| --- |
| 21788 |
| 2278 |
| 278 |
| 241740 |

I want the SQL output to be

| RowA |
| --- |
| 2hr17min |
| 22min |
| 2min |
| 24hr17min |

I tried with below query but I can't get proper mins.

```
substr(to_CHAR(ROWA), 1, length(ROWA) - 4) || 'Hrs' || 
substr(to_CHAR(ROWA), 2, length(ROWA) - 3) || 'Mins'
```

Format is like HHMMSS

Comment: Looks like a bit more than only adding characters

Comment: Can you explain the logic and tell us what datatype the column is

Comment: Its a string i tried substr(to_CHAR(ROWA),1,length(ROWA)-4) ||'Hrs'||substr(to_CHAR(ROWA),2,length(ROWA)-3)||'Mins' but I can't formulate mins

Comment: Please do not add the `mysql` it is different from oracle sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple string functions:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN LENGTH(rowa) > 4
       THEN SUBSTR(rowa, 1, LENGTH(rowa) - 4) || 'hr'
       END
    || CASE
       WHEN LENGTH(rowa) >= 4
       THEN SUBSTR(rowa, -4, 2) || 'min'
       WHEN LENGTH(rowa) > 2
       THEN SUBSTR(rowa, 1, LENGTH(rowa) - 2) || 'min'
       END AS duration
FROM   my_tests;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_tests ( RowA ) AS
SELECT '21788' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2278' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '278' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '241740' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DURATION |
| --- |
| 2hr17min |
| 22min |
| 2min |
| 24hr17min |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KoI5sQ7r)

Comment: Thanks. Your script works exactly like I need